# Customizing UIAlertView in a simple manner

Tags: ios, uitableview, uialertview

my question for the stack is how to customize the 'message' part of UIAlertView. Right now, the message is [dbName] which is the selected row in the table. How am I able to change the message to something like. @"Would you like to add 'dbName' to the database?"

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{


Database * currentStore = [DBList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *dbName = currentStore.databaseName;


UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Camaleon Alert" message:dbName delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
// optional - add more buttons:
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Add"];
[alert show];




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something as easy as:

```
NSString *messageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Would you like to add '%@' to the database?",currentStore.databaseName];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Camaleon Alert" messageString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```